# Who/What exactly is the Client Application in the Open ID Connect Auth Code Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, single-page-application, openid, openid-connect

From an OpenID perspective and all questions/articles I've read, it seems pretty self-explanatory - it is the client application requesting for the ID Token. However, when I try to map it an actual "application" in our architecture, I'm not exactly sure.

Given:

- ID_Token's audience is intended for the Client_Application
- Access_Token's audience is intended for the Protected Resource API
- We have an front-end SPA that has its own back-end web API (which may later be consumed by other clients)

The components involved are:

1. Front-end SPA (Relying Party)
2. Back-end Web_API (Protected Resource)
3. OpenID Provider (OP)

If I wanted to apply the Auth Code flow when a user accesses the Front-end SPA, would the Front-End SPA OR Web_API be considered the Client_Application? In Auth Code flow, the actual exchange of an Auth_Code for ID_Token would happen back-channel, via the Back-end Web_API to the OP. Yet, it's really the Front-end SPA that initially requested for the authentication of the user. What should/would the audience of the ID_Token be - would it be the SPA's or Web_API's App_ID?

Thanks for any help with the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current best practice require SPA to use authorization code flow with PKCE ([draft best practice rfc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.1)). So please consider this when using OAuth with your SPA.

Regarding your doubt, here are your client and audiences

- **Client** - Your SPA
- Audience of **ID Token** - Your SPA
- Audience of **Access token** - Backend web API

Justification :

It is your SPA which completes the OAuth flow and obtain tokens. And as I said, it must follow PKCE as current recomendation (there are enough libraries to support this). So from authorization  server perspective, client is your SPA.

Regarding ID Token, it is intended to be consumed by your SPA. Once validated SPA authenticate the end user. So it intended audience is SPA.

Access token is intended to be used against your backend by your SPA. Once it receive an API request, it must check access token audience contain identifier targeting itself (ex:- If a JWT, claim containing backend identifeir. Or if token introspection, the resposne containing the identifier). Usually your authorization server allows you to register such audiences and your authorization request can have intended audience parameter (ex:- Azure use this approach). But these are implementation specifics.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From my understanding, PKCE was introduced to address pure SPAs that have no backend and hence, no secure way to exchange auth_code for id_token. But let's just say in my example, the SPA isn't a pure SPA, but has a backend, which is somewhat coupled to the SPA for authentication. Would you still suggest using PKCE?

Comment: As a different example, let's say we have a non-SPA front-end web_app with a dedicated back_end. I would assume this falls under the standard auth code flow scenario, wherein, the front-end app triggers the auth flow, but the back-end completes it. Would we still assign a different client_id to front-end vs back-end, and who would be considered the client_application to the OP now? Or is that in this case, both front-end and back-end are considered a single client_application?

Comment: @sherman PKCE helps to stop token stealing for public clients (client without a client secret). Yes PKCE is recommended now for all client types which use auth code flow. I think you can rely on libraries to get this done. In the given scenario full web app is considered as the client (single client). And front and backend work together to obtain token.

Comment: are you saying even if if a client has the option of using back-channel auth code flow (i.e. client secret can be protected), PKCE is still preferred? if that's the case, should we ever use back-channel auth code flow?

Comment: @sherman In case client has a secret, I would say it is optional. But read the draft (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.1) which say it's an advice.